# Is it possible to make the set $M:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y=|x|\}$ into a differentiable manifold?

Tags: differential-topology, manifolds

1) Is it possible that be given a suitable smooth atlas to the set $M:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: y=|x|\}$ so that $M$ to be a differentiable manifold? Why? How?

2) How can I prove that M is not an embedded smooth  submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

In really, How can I show that  $M$ is not the image of any $C^{\infty}$- immersion of $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 6):

Via [transport of structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure), any set with the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$ (such as your set $M$) can be given the structure of a smooth manifold in such a way that it is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

In other words, simply choose a bijection $f:\mathbb{R}\to M$ (there's an obvious one in your case), then

- define a topology on $M$ by declaring that, for every open set $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, the set $f(U)$ will be an open set of the topology on $M$, then
- define an atlas on $M$ by declaring that, for every chart $(U,\psi:U\to V)$ of the usual atlas of $\mathbb{R}$, the chart $(f(U),(\psi\circ f^{-1}):f(U)\to V))$ will be an element of the atlas on $M$

In fact, in the case of your set $M$ (with its subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}^2$), the obvious bijection $f:\mathbb{R}\to M$ is already a homeomorphism, so there is no need to declare a new topology on $M$ as I described in my first step.

Comment: Let M is without topology(an abstract set). What is your $f$? I guess that your $\psi\circ f^{-1}$ to be not $C^{\infty}$.

Comment: @bigli: Before you can even talk about whether a function on a topological space is $C^\infty$ or not, *you first have to have specified a smooth atlas*. My second bullet point is defining an atlas on $M$ - check all of the necessary properties.

Comment: Actually, a better question woul dhave been: "Is it possible that be given a smooth atlas to the *topological space*$M=\ldots$"

Comment: How can I show that all of $\psi\circ f^{-1}$ are $C^{\infty}$ related?

Comment: @bigli all transiotin maps between two open sets $U,V\subseteq \mathbb R$ are simply the identity on $U\cap V$.

Comment: Now,I understand your answer completely. You are right. Hence M is a differentiable manifold. But I asked you, my second question:  How can I prove that $M$ is not an embedded smooth  submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @ZevChonoles: That's what I call a dungeon article. No 10 edits, no references, 2 articles linking to it.

Comment: @ZevChonoles:What is your idea about my second question in the begining of this post?

Answer (score 5):

> A differentiable manifold is a topological manifold equipped with an atlas whose transition maps are all differentiable.

Now by assuming that $M$ is a topological manifold, one can define an atlas on $M$ which have only one chart!

Consider chart $(M,\varphi)$ where its coordinate function, $\varphi$, is defined as follows:

$$\varphi:M\to \mathbb{R}$$
$$\varphi (x,|x|):=(x,0)$$

and its inverse is

$$\varphi^{-1}:\mathbb{R}\to M$$
$$\varphi^{-1} (x)=(x,|x|)$$

easily you can show the map is homeomorphism. The only transition map is identity map that is smooth, clearly. **So, $M$ is a smooth manifold.**

Comment: What is your idea about my second question in the begining of this post?

Comment: $\varphi^{-1}$ is not differentiable in $0$, so there is a problem in your answer. In other hand, What is your idea about my second question in the begining of this post?

Comment: @bigli- By definition of the differentiable manifold, only **transition maps** must be differentiable, not coordinate functions!

Comment: @Bakhoda-I do not find out your last comment, explain it.

Comment: Do you know definitions of **transition map** and **coordinate function** and differences between them?

Comment: No, I don't. What's?

Comment: I suggest you, study [Differentiable manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold) completely and come back to continue the discussion.

Comment: In fact it doesn't even make sense to say that the coordinate function is not differentiable - the very notion of differentiability requires a smooth structure and the smooth structure is essentially *defined* by the fact that the coordinate functions are smooth.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your last question, by considering left and right-sided derivatives, show that the derivative of any such immersion at a point in the preimage of the origin must lie in the tangent space (at the origin) of the graph of line y= -x and in the tangent space  (at the origin) of the graph of the line y=x (both such tangent spaces thought of as linear subspaces of $T_{(0,0)}(\mathbb{R}^2$)). Since the intersection of these spaces is 0, the derivative cannot be injective here.